# I can not find the location of the sbtach.c file in slurm

Tags: slurm

I installed slurm on my local PC to perform some tests, but I need the sbatch.c file, but I can not find it, I installed the slurm with:

Sudo apt-get install -y slurm-wlm slurm-wlm-doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in SLURM source code at Github. The file you are looking for is this one (remember to select your version tag):
https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/sbatch/sbatch.c

Or downloading the package that contain all the sources form the SLURM Official Downloads:
https://www.schedmd.com/downloads.php

(the file you are looking for is at src/sbatch/sbatch.c)

You can look for a specific file in your Ubuntu repositories, using `apt-file` or `dpkg -S`. Having all repos enabled you can try to find it with:

```
apt-file search sbatch.c

dpkg -S sbatch.c
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *sbatch.c*
```

But in this case, as you can see, nothing appears.

Comment: Then, if I download and install slurm from the official webpage will I have the sbatch.c file in my system? or there is not way to have it? I need to work on that file ..

Comment: Yes. If you are going to work with the source that will be the right way to do it.
Uninstall the Ubuntu repo version, download the sources, follow the guide to install it at: https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart_admin.html

And then, if you want/need to modify sbatch.c, you can do it, and run make && make install again.